# Error: Could not find or load main class Disneyland

Tags: java, readfile

My code compiles and I have two text files that need to be read from the program but when I run the program I get the following error: the menuItems.txt contains:
Churro
Ice Cream
Hamburger
Cheese burger
Turkey Leg
Corn Dog
Pizza
Funnel Cake
Soda

The priceItems contains:
5
4
9
10
13
7
9
6
5
All Files are located on my desktop

Error: Could not find or load main class Disneyland
    package com.Kassie$;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Disneyland {
//Initialize the items 1D array
public static String[] getItems() {
   try {
       //Read from file
       String[] aItems = new String(Files.readAllBytes
           (Paths.get("src/com/Kassie$/desktop/menuItems.txt")))
           .split("\n");
       return aItems;
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
}
//Initialize the items 1D array
public static String[] getPrices() {
   try {
       //Read from file
           String[] aPrices = new String(Files.readAllBytes
           (Paths.get("src/com/Kassie$/desktop/menuPrices.txt")))
           .split("\n");
           return aPrices;
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;  
}
// Find the character's location
public static String findLocation(String[][] storedValue, String name) {
   for(int i = 0; i < storedValue.length; i++) {
       if(storedValue[i][0].equals(name)) {
           return (storedValue[i][1]);
       }
   }
   return null;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
   char choice = ' ';
   int totPrice = 0;
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   String[][] characterLocation = {{"Mickey Mouse","Main Street USA"},
       {"Minnie Mouse", "Toon Town"},
       {"Goofy","Frontier Land"},
       {"Pluto","Tomorrowland"},
       {"Belle","Fantasyland"},
       {"Jasmine", "Adventureland"}};
   System.out.println("Do you like to know the "
       + "Disney Character's location(Y/N)?");
   choice = s.next().charAt(0);
   if(choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y') {
       System.out.println("Enter the name of the character");
       String aName = s.next();
       String location = findLocation(characterLocation,aName);
       if( location != null) {
           System.out.println("The character is located in " + location);
       }
       else {
           System.out.println("Sorry! The character you are looking for "
               + "is not in park today");
       }
   }
   String[] items = getItems();
   String[] prices = getPrices();
   choice = ' ';
   System.out.println("Would you like to view the menu?(Y/N)");
   choice = s.next().charAt(0);
   if(choice == 'N' || choice == 'n') {
       System.exit(0);
   }
   while(choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y') {
       for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
           System.out.println("Enter " + (i+1) + " for " + items[i]);
       }
       int option = s.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Item : " + items[option-1]);
       System.out.println("Price : " + prices[option-1]);
       totPrice = totPrice + Integer.parseInt(prices[option-1]);
       System.out.println("Do you want to order more(Y/N)?");
       choice = s.next().charAt(0);
   }
   System.out.println("Are you an Annual Pass Holder?(Y/N)?");
   choice = s.next().charAt(0);
   if(choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y') {
       System.out.println("Your bill amount due : $" +        ((double)totPrice -
   ((double)(totPrice*15))/100));
       System.exit(1);
   }
   System.out.println("Your bill amount due : $" + totPrice);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the dollar sign in your path.

To match a dollar sign, use **"\$"**

```
public static String[] getPrices() {
   try {
       //Read from file
           String[] aPrices = new String(Files.readAllBytes
           (Paths.get("src/com/Kassie\\$/desktop/menuPrices.txt")))
           .split("\n");
           return aPrices;
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;  
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I got an error saying that \ wasn't suppose to be there